# Looping through Subsetted Data R

Tags: r, subset

Looking to calculate the mean of Value by region for every Label and save this to a new dataframe. As I have a huge dataset I would need a loop - any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
structure(list(Label = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), Region = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("EUR", "GLB", "UK"), class = "factor"), 
Value = c(-6, 17, 26, -37, 44, -22, 15, 12)), .Names = c("Label", 
"Region", "Value"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `aggregate(Value~., df1, mean)`

Comment: @akrun beat me by a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks but where in your comment are you referencing Label and Region? I have other numerous non used columns. Thanks